# How do give path to config module in sub directory?

Tags: node.js, express, config

I've installed node **config** module using `npm install config`.

Now, my app.js file (server) is in say directory `/node`. I have another folder inside /node, **controllers**.

The default config folder that contains default.js file is also in /node.

Inside controllers, I have following code in JS file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const config = require('config');
```

First 4 modules are included successfully. But 5th shows following error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'config'

I tried several times to change paths for it, including absolute path but showed similar error.

Now how can I give it proper path?

EDIT: Directory structure:

```
/node
. /config
  . default.js
. node_modules
. /controllers
  . myfile.js
  . other files
. app.js
```

Comment: I have used `npm install config -save` and included the module in my file and it worked..

Comment: Please answer my question.

Comment: Config should be included in `app.js` not in controllers. Tried same as you described not getting error, please check may be you are doing something wrong.

Comment: There's no relation between app.js and my js file, that's why I am getting this error. I need to use that config folder inside controllers. Any way to achieve this? I'm not including it in my app.js file.

Comment: Did you run `npm install config` inside the `/node` directory?

Comment: Yes, I did in node directory. Any problem with that?

Comment: No, that's the correct way. Can you see a `config/` directory in `/node/node_modules`?

Comment: Yes, there is a config directory there.

Comment: What should I do next?

Comment: If your controller file has no relation with the `app.js` then how did you execute this. not getting the exact scenario, can you give structure detail of your app.

Comment: I run it using `node myfile.js`. I have updated structure.

Comment: created same structure as you have. `config` module working fine for me.

Comment: After a lot research i get to know how `require` exactly work refer this blog https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm and according to this there is no problem in your structure and code. Please create a new app or install `config` again may be you are missing something.

Comment: The config is installed properly. Now the exact issue is: "Can't find config direcotry" because it's in /node, but it is expecting it in /controllers